# Why did my query run very slow on a mongos

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongos which connects to three shard cluster. I have a few databases and collections in this mongos instance. All other collections work fine except one has a performance issue. It takes 45 minutes to run below command

```
db.orders.find().explain('executionStats')
```

The total number document in this collection is `111898400`. Each shard cluster has about `30000000` documents. I know that I didn't run this query against the shard key but I just wonder whether this is the reason why it takes so long. I expect it takes a few minutes at most but not 45 minutes.

Below is the execution stats from above command. How can I profile it more to find out why it takes so long?

```
"executionStats" : {
        "nReturned" : 111432926,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 2727745,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 111899059,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "SHARD_MERGE",
            "nReturned" : 111432926,
            "executionTimeMillis" : 2727745,
            "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
            "totalDocsExamined" : 111899059,
            "totalChildMillis" : NumberLong(6550367),
            "shards" : [
                {
                    "shardName" : "s0",
                    "executionSuccess" : true,
                    "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "SHARDING_FILTER",
                        "nReturned" : 36545358,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2723505,
                        "works" : 36613353,
                        "advanced" : 36545358,
                        "needTime" : 67994,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 321990,
                        "restoreState" : 321990,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "chunkSkips" : 67993,
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                            "nReturned" : 36613351,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2689811,
                            "works" : 36613353,
                            "advanced" : 36613351,
                            "needTime" : 1,
                            "needYield" : 0,
                            "saveState" : 321990,
                            "restoreState" : 321990,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "invalidates" : 0,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "docsExamined" : 36613351
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "shardName" : "s1",
                    "executionSuccess" : true,
                    "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "SHARDING_FILTER",
                        "nReturned" : 36423091,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1647595,
                        "works" : 36423093,
                        "advanced" : 36423091,
                        "needTime" : 1,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 305586,
                        "restoreState" : 305586,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "chunkSkips" : 0,
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                            "nReturned" : 36423091,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1614736,
                            "works" : 36423093,
                            "advanced" : 36423091,
                            "needTime" : 1,
                            "needYield" : 0,
                            "saveState" : 305586,
                            "restoreState" : 305586,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "invalidates" : 0,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "docsExamined" : 36423091
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "shardName" : "s2",
                    "executionSuccess" : true,
                    "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "SHARDING_FILTER",
                        "nReturned" : 38464477,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2166740,
                        "works" : 38862619,
                        "advanced" : 38464477,
                        "needTime" : 398141,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 331525,
                        "restoreState" : 331525,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "chunkSkips" : 398140,
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                            "nReturned" : 38862617,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2128083,
                            "works" : 38862619,
                            "advanced" : 38862617,
                            "needTime" : 1,
                            "needYield" : 0,
                            "saveState" : 331525,
                            "restoreState" : 331525,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "invalidates" : 0,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "docsExamined" : 38862617
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the size of the collection says it all. The query retrieves **all** the documents at their full shape from all shards, sends them over the network and then merges them into a single result.

Actually, at this number of records, I wouldn't find 45 minutes too much for a fullscan.

Comment: The total size of the collection is 12GB

Comment: Well the size is not too big indeed, but it's still quite large number of individual records to be read from disk brute-force; no filtering conditions, no projection, just rough reading. You should still take in account possible fragmentation (might be caused by other freuquently modified collection in the same datafiles), the hardware performance, other processes that might compete with mongod on individual shards etc. Have a look at `top` and `iotop` while running this query.